# Novo procedimento não é exibido no SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Seguir os passos no doc na microsoft:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017#SSMSProcedure

Alterei as permissões porém não consegui exibir "novo procedimento" ao clicar na pasta novo procedimento

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha cara, quando tive este problema, eu tive que conseguir a senha definida para o administrador, no ato da instalação, acredito que somente com ele você vai conseguir acessar o banco com todos os privilégios para criar isto, ou acessar a segurança para dar acesso de criação deste tipo de objeto a outros usuários.

Eu utilizo o usuário "SA", mas acesse ele com a senha do ato da instalação.

Answer (score 0):

Como alternativa podes usar criar via codigo.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NOME_DO_PROCEDIMENTO  
AS  
BEGIN  
-- CORPO DO PROCEDIMENTO 
END;
```